# Migrate from TopicProcessor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

TopicProcessor has been removed since the 3.4+ reactor version and now I'm struggling how is the easiest way to replace it with a new API. I'd like to keep the implementation as reliable as possible, even if the performance will get worst. I don't want to struggle with loss events or an overflowing stream, just keep it stupid simple. I also need to buffer data, so I've used `bufferTimeout` for that and it worked perfectly with `TopicProcessor`.
How to achieve that with the new API?

I've tried to use `Sinks` but with a lot of pressure there was an overflow exception and the whole stream was terminated.

Below is my basic implementation before upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4.1.

```
package com.example.reactorplayground.config;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class TopicProcessor<T> implements Processor<T> {
    private final reactor.core.publisher.TopicProcessor<T> processor;

    public TopicProcessor() {
        this.processor = reactor.core.publisher.TopicProcessor.share("in-memory-topic-thread", 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<T> add(T event) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            processor.onNext(event);
            return event;
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<T> consumeWith() {
        return processor;
    }
}
```